# How to rotate an image on command using Codename One's Transform class?

Tags: java, codenameone

I am currently doing a school project where we are creating an Asteroids game using Codename One. My current functionality works well, except for when it comes to rotating the image of the ship. Using the Transform class has been ineffective; the image does not rotate, no matter how the Transform is applied or the image is drawn.

Here is a sample portion of the code used to turn:

```
public void turnRight() //Rotates the ship 5 degrees clockwise
{
    if (direction==355)
        direction = 0;
    else
        direction+=5;
    Transform tmpTransform = Transform.makeIdentity();
    theImage.getGraphics().getTransform(tmpTransform);
    tmpTransform.rotate((float)Math.toRadians(5), x, y);
    theImage.getGraphics().setTransform(tmpTransform);
    theImage.getGraphics().drawImage(shipPic, 0, 0);
}
```

Where:

- theImage is a mutable Image (100x100)
- shipPic is an Image created via Image.createImage(String path)

In addition, I have tried using the draw(Graphics g, Point p) method and passing theImage.getGraphics(), as well as passing shipPic.getGraphics()
I am at a loss, and Codename One's documentation on the subject is unhelpful.

Could I get some assistance, please?

Comment: Not sure if this will cover everything you need, but here’s a blog post where an animated clock was created. https://www.codenameone.com/blog/codename-one-graphics-low-level-animations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one graphics object so something like this:

Graphics g = theImage.getGraphics();

Would be more correct. You also must test for transform support when rendering onto an image as low level graphics isn't always portable to all OS's in all surfaces. A good example is iOS where rendering onto an image uses a completely different low level implementation than the display rendering.

Normally I would render directly to the display as that is hardware accelerated on modern devices and images are often implemented in software.

About the documentation, did you read the [graphics section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/graphics.html) in the developer guide?

It should contain explanations of everything and if something is missing there is [search](https://www.codenameone.com/search.html). If you still can't find something and figure it out by yourself notice you can also [edit the docs](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-edit-docs-fun-profit.html) and help us improve them.

Comment: Perspective transform is not supported on the simulator, however affine transform is.
In addition, there are the following problems:
- g.getTransform() is deprecated only when the graphics are stored in an object
- Most manuals and documentation do not actually instruct on how to transform an image
- 2D affine transformations are _completely_ undocumented (see:  https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Transform.html#rotate-float-float-float- )

Thank you for the advice, however.

Comment: Perspective is problematic on the simulator as Java SE doesn't really support proper perspective transform in `Graphics2D`. There is a deprecation comment that specifically points to `getTransform(Transform t)` which is used to reduce generated memory garbage.  There is some discussion of this in the javadocs too, did you look there: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/ looking at the `Transform` class and other classes I agree we could use more samples there though.

Comment: I've asked Steve about this and he generally agrees this can use more samples, he pointed me at this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/perspective-transform.html

Comment: I believe there might have been a miscommunication; I am attempting an affine (2D) transform, not a perspective transform. I mentioned the support because you did, I'm sorry if I confused you. It doesn't matter as much anymore as I've made headway by inspecting the professor's demo code. More examples in the docs would be helpful for others, though, thank you.

Comment: I understood that, I assumed you already found the clock demo which is in the developer guide and site. Since you mentioned transforms in general I gave that example too. Low level graphics is pretty hard so our main focus is on the higher level API's which are more commonly used. Eventually we'll probably make our way down with examples but that's a bit more challenging as there are so many options